# How to skip illegal escape sequence value for Jena

Tags: rdf, jena, apache-jena

During reading a large turtle file with the following code using Jena, I got the error `org.apache.jena.riot.RiotException: [line: NUM, col: NUM] illegal escape sequence value` and the code stopped.

```
Model model = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();
try {
    InputStream in = FileManager.get().open("FILE.ttl");
    model.read(in, null, "TTL");
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I can resolve the error by replacing the line with the correct one. But I would like to skip and ignore the line, if it has a problem. Is it possible?

Comment: Turtle isn't line based, so skipping a line isn't really an option,  in general.  Eg, if `:foo` is one line and `:p :bar .` is the next, you couldn't skip either one without doing something about the other.

Comment: The best option is probably to preprocess the file and turn the not-actually-Turtle file into a Turtle file.